# Multiple $.ajax calls in a web page

Tags: jquery, ajax

If a web page makes multiple, non-simultaneous ajax calls over the period of days to get updated information, is there a possibility of a memory leak or many (thousands) unused objects hanging around that could cause a browser or system failure?

Comment: Is there a possibility? Sure. Keeping a dynamic web page up for days/weeks is a bit more challenging than most people assume...

Comment: Agree.  But is there some coding technique I should use to reclaim/discard memory/object?

Comment: Nullify the XHR object and all possible variables that you create within an ajax request. Also you may use refreshing the page to clear all allocated memories.

Comment: Thanks Ali! My code is "$.ajax({ ... });"  How would I nullify that? I'm guessing to make it more like "ajaxObj = $.ajax({ ... });" then later "ajaxObj = null;". Is that more like it? And inside for result testing, instead of "error: function ( ... ){ ... };" do "error: myError (...);"?

Comment: I´d also say (programmatically) refreshing the page seems like the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // First AJAX call
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.example.com/data1', // Replace with your API endpoint URL
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json', // Set the expected data type
    success: function (data) {
      // Handle the data returned from the server
      console.log('Data 1:', data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      // Handle errors if the AJAX call fails
      console.error('Error in AJAX call 1:', error);
    },
  });

  // Second AJAX call
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.example.com/data2', // Replace with your API endpoint URL
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      param1: 'value1',
      param2: 'value2',
    },
    dataType: 'json', // Set the expected data type
    success: function (data) {
      // Handle the data returned from the server
      console.log('Data 2:', data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      // Handle errors if the AJAX call fails
      console.error('Error in AJAX call 2:', error);
    },
  });

  // You can add more AJAX calls as needed
});
```